# How to use JSONObject as @Body in Retrofit (POST)?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I can successfully generate a JSONObject.

```
{
  "cf-field": {
    "pdf-name": "CAPTAIN BOBOYz",
    "pdf-email": "boy@test.com",
    "pdf-phone": "09054323769",
    "pdf-progress": "forwarded",
    "pdf-street_address": "",
    "pdf-state": "Nevada",
    "pdf-zipcode": "10278",
    "pdf-city": "New York",
    "pdf-lead_type": "form submission",
    "pdf-lead_source": "Organic"
  },
  "lead_id": "273993"
}
```

But when I use :

```
@Headers(PARAM_HEADER_JSON)
    @POST(HttpConstants.LEAD_EDIT)
    Call<LeadDetailsResult> updateLead(@Header(PARAM_TOKEN) String token, @Body JSONObject jsonObject);
```

The json changed and looked like this:

```
{
  "nameValuePairs": {
    "cf-field": {
      "nameValuePairs": {
        "pdf-name": "CAPTAIN BOBOYz",
        "pdf-email": "boy@test.com",
        "pdf-phone": "09054323769",
        "pdf-progress": "forwarded",
        "pdf-street_address": "",
        "pdf-state": "Nevada",
        "pdf-zipcode": "10278",
        "pdf-city": "New York",
        "pdf-lead_type": "form submission",
        "pdf-lead_source": "Organic"
      },
      "NEGATIVE_ZERO": 0
    },
    "lead_id": "273993"
  },
  "NEGATIVE_ZERO": 0
}
```

I used JSONObject because what I'm passing is a dynamic data. This is the first time I encountered such feature. I hope you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

**Use JsonObject instead of JSONObject**

Follow this steps

1. Add `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'` Dependency
2. Add this sample json conversion for test

   ```
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject jsonfieldObject = new JsonObject();

    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-name", "CAPTAIN BOBOYz");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-email","boy@test.com");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-phone", "09054323769");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-progress", "forwarded");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-street_address", "");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-state", "Nevada");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-zipcode", "10278");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-city", "New York");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-lead_type", "form submission");
    jsonfieldObject.addProperty("pdf-lead_source", "Organic");

    jsonObject.add("cf-field",jsonfieldObject);
    jsonObject.addProperty("lead_id","273993");

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: jsonObject-->"+jsonObject);
   ```
3. output

   {
   "cf-field": {
   "pdf-name": "CAPTAIN BOBOYz",
   "pdf-email": "boy@test.com",
   "pdf-phone": "09054323769",
   "pdf-progress": "forwarded",
   "pdf-street_address": "",
   "pdf-state": "Nevada",
   "pdf-zipcode": "10278",
   "pdf-city": "New York",
   "pdf-lead_type": "form submission",
   "pdf-lead_source": "Organic"
   },
   "lead_id": "273993"
   }
4. Post/Pass that JsonObject to retrofit service

@Headers(PARAM_HEADER_JSON)
@POST(HttpConstants.LEAD_EDIT)
Call updateLead(@Header(PARAM_TOKEN) String token, @Body JsonObject jsonObject);

> Please Except the answer if it work for you.